# show/hide twitter bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using bootstrap to display content below tabs, but I want to collapse the tabs when the tab is clicked again.  Here is the code I tried to get to work, to no avail:

```
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="square"><a class="story" href="#article1" data-toggle="tab"><img src="#"/></a></li>
        <li class="square"><a class="story" href="#article2" data-toggle="tab"><img src="#g"/></a></li>
        <li class="square"><a class="story" href="#article3" data-toggle="tab"><img src="#"/></a></li>
               <div id="article1" class="tab-pane fade"><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></div>
               <div id="article2" class="tab-pane fade"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p</div>
               <div id="article3" class="tab-pane fade"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
    </ul>

<script>
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
            if($(this).tab.hasClass('active')){
                    $(this).tab('hide');
                } else {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).tab('show');
                    }
                })
</script>
```

I'm not sure if tabs are supposed to work this way...should I try the collapse functionality?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like you want [Bootstrap's collapse widget](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse). That said, this jQuery will hide an already active tab:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        $( $(this).attr('href') ).hide();
    }
});​
```

The problem is that this prevents a hidden tab from being shown again, so I don't think you'll want to use it. See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/NQ97h/

If you want to be able to bring the tab back, try:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        var target_pane=$(this).attr('href');
        $( target_pane ).toggle( !$( target_pane ).is(":visible") );
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/epT3L/ for this solution.

Comment: Oh, and if you wanted to make this re-usable, you'd want to select `$('.nav a')`, not `$('#myTab a')`...

Comment: Thanks, I actually switched it to regular jquery slideToggle, with some success.

Comment: I tried this, but if you want to re-enable the tab, it wont work.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann: if you want to bring it back (which the original poster did not request), try `$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        var target_pane=$(this).attr('href');
        $( target_pane ).toggle( !$( target_pane ).is(":visible") );
    }
});` See http://jsfiddle.net/epT3L/

Comment: Downwoted as the solution is incomplete, i.e. when a tab is hidden it is remain hidden even after switching from another tab

Answer (score 20):

Here's a tweak of Jeromy's solution that I believe does what you want:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    var tab = $(this);
    if(tab.parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $(".tab-pane").removeClass('active');
            tab.parent('li').removeClass('active');
        },1);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NQ97h/39/

Comment: That works, btw. there's no need for timeout value as the function will be executed after running the message queue of current stack even when it's omitted

Comment: and add `} else { tab.tab('show'); }` to make tabs togglable

Comment: I couldn't get it to work without the setTimeout (https://jsfiddle.net/5f2wvgxq/1/), but, whatever (tested on Safari 7.1.3). And the else clause you suggested doesn't seem to make a difference (https://jsfiddle.net/5f2wvgxq/2/).  The tabs in fiddle I referenced in my answer are already togglable. Sorry, I'm probably just misunderstanding.

Comment: I meant the "timeout value" of `1` ms that can be omitted, not the `setTimeout` function itself. http://jsfiddle.net/NQ97h/662/. I have to add that it's not suited for Dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

I've got a version that works (in my case, just for the main tabs, you'll have to modify it to handle the dropdown tabs.)  I just threw it into a fork of Jeromy's jsfiddle above: http://jsfiddle.net/HsqQQ/3/

Here's the code:

```
 $(document).off('click.tab.data-api');
    $(document).on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab = $($(this).attr('href'));
        var activate = !tab.hasClass('active');
        $('div.tab-content>div.tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');
        $('ul.nav.nav-tabs>li.active').removeClass('active');
        if (activate) {
            $(this).tab('show')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem and solved by modifying the bootstrap.js.

Find the tab class definition (usually line 1783) on `Tab.prototype.show` function and modify:

`if ($this.parent('li').hasClass('active')) return`

to

```
if ($this.parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
            $this.parent('li').removeClass('active')
            $(selector).removeClass('active')
            return
        }
```

Then it will work as expected and without creating more "custom scripts" in your project.

EDIT:

This modification affects EVERY tab panel in your project, however, if you want to make this effect only on desired objects you'll need to add some `data-hide` or something like that, such as:

```
if ($this.parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
            if ($this.parent('li').attr('data-hide') == "on") {
                $this.parent('li').removeClass('active')
                $(selector).removeClass('active')
            }
            return
        }
```

then, every parent `<li>` with `data-hide` will hide when click.

Answer (score 0):

I get a working bootstrap pills navigation which supports open/close toogle with this code:

```
jQuery(function() {
// Closing active pill when clicking on toggle:
jQuery(document).off('click.bs.tab.data-api');
jQuery(document).on('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="pill"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var activeClass = 'active';
    var tab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var tab = tab && tab.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, ''); // strip for ie7
    var tab = jQuery(tab);
    if (!tab.hasClass(activeClass)) {
        jQuery(this).tab('show');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass(activeClass);
        tab.parent().children().removeClass(activeClass);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

What about to do something like that? `show.bs.tab` will always fire before `click` and it will give to `click` the right status

```
$(document).on('show.bs.tab', '#myTab a', function(e) {
   if (!$(e.target).hasClass('active')) {
      $(e.target).addClass('monkeyPatch');
   }
});

$(document).on('click', '#myTab a', function(e) {
   var tab = $(this);
   if (tab.hasClass('monkeyPatch')) {
      tab.removeClass('monkeyPatch');
   } else {
      $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
      tab.parent('li').removeClass('active');
   }
});
```